# import / require always return empty object

Tags: javascript, typescript, meteor

On the server, I try to import npm pkg [colors](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js) after I installed it.

I tried every way but always got an empty object while import it:

1. `import * as colors from 'colors/safe';`
2. `import colors from 'colors/safe';`
3. `const colors = require('colors/safe');`

The output of console.debug(colors) is always {}

Enviroments on server: Meteor + typescript. The tsconfig.json settings are:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015",
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "stripInternal": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: There is no problem in your writing.Add some console output in colors.js,I think there would be something wrong.

Comment: There are several different ways to set up TypeScript compilation with Meteor, so I can't easily speculate on what is happening.  Can you reproduce the problem in a new project that has no code except for the import and the `console.debug`?  If so, please publish the repository and I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

```
import colors from 'colors';
colors.enabled = true; // This is important
console.log(colors.green('I am green'));
```

Try this

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'enabled' of undefined